# Firebase functions serve is not working anymore

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I don't know what exactly happened, but once it stopped to work.

I'm getting following error:
`⚠  ui: Fatal error occurred:  Emulator UI has exited with code: 1,`

And logs:

```
/Users/maz/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.11.7/server/server.js:3292
    "chars": "\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uF
                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1162:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
```

I tried to re-install node, firebase tools, cleaning cache, restarting comp, everything I could do, but it didn't work. I expect it to work as it worked in the beginning

Comment: Let me know if the suggestion below worked? if not will solve further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to corrupted ZIP files in the current versions you are using. It has been fixed in `firebase-tools` [`v11.30`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v11.30.0). Hence try to install the latest version using the below command.

```
npm i firebase-tools@latest
```

Or

```
npm i firebase-tools@11.30.0
```

Also try to upgrade `node` version.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I wasted so many hours trying to fix it..)